# Apple Siri Intent stops playback without apparent reason

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, siri, sirishortcuts

I would like to improve the integration of my App [FM-Pod](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/fm-pod-radio-streaming/id1435532223?mt=8) with Siri intents shortcuts. I've done this App to listen the radio on the HomePod and, as of now, I've been able to start the playback, change the stations, etc. but I'm facing a strange issue which causes the audio playback to stop alone after about 1 minute...

Does anyone knows the reason? What's wrong?

Here is the code in Swift for starting the playback, leveraging on AVAudioPlayer:

```
open func handle(intent: StartFMPodIntent, completion: @escaping (StartFMPodIntentResponse) -> Void) {

    DataManager.getStationDataWithSuccess(filename: "favorites") { (data) in
        if debug { print("Stations JSON Found") }
        guard let data = data, let jsonDictionary = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String: [RadioStation]].self, from: data), let stationsArray = jsonDictionary["station"]
            else {
                if debug { print("JSON Station Loading Error") }
                return
        }
            HPRIntentHandler.stations = stationsArray
            if !FRadioPlayer.shared.isPlaying {
                FRadioPlayer.shared.radioURL = URL(string: HPRIntentHandler.stations![0].streamURL0!)
                let response = StartFMPodIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
                response.stationName = stationsArray[0].name
                completion(response)
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2

Extension is killed after code is finished running.
Since the getStationDataWithSuccess run in Asynchronously, its code reaches the end before the asynchronous function finishes running.
You have to find different place to handle this.

Comment: I got your point, thanks. I can try to read the file synchronously. Although I have to precise that the “completion(response)” is reached because Siri is acknowledging with the stationName as expected.